# In Laravel, can we sum related models attribute using withCount method?

Tags: laravel

I have 3 models related like so :
`Prize -> TimeSlot -> Winner`, with their corresponding relationship methods `$prize->hasMany(TimeSlot)` and `$prize->hasManyThrough(Winner, TimeSlot)`.

I am trying to count in one eloquent query the number of winners and the number of time slots.

Here is the query :

```
$prizes = $prizes->withCount(['winners', 'timeSlots' => function ($query) {
    $query->sum('min'); // min is an attribute on TimeSlot
}])->get();
```

This gives me the number of winners with a `winners_count` attribute on each prize. I thought it would give me the 'sum number' of time slots for each prize but the query breaks on that part with an error like :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'prizes.id' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select sum(`min`) as aggregate from `time_slots` where `time_slots`.`prize_id` = `prizes`.`id`)
```

The documentation of `withCount` method only show how to constraint the query (with a where clause for example) but not with an aggregate like sum.

P.S: I already know how to do this with something like :

```
$prizes = $prizes->with('timeSlots')->withCount('winners')->get();

$numOfWinners = $prizes->sum('winners_count');

$numOfAvailablePrizes = $prizes->sum(function ($prize) {
    return $prize->timeSlots()->sum('min');
});
```

But i thought the version with one query would save me some useless loops...

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
$query->withCount(['timeSlots AS timeslots_sum' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(min) as timeslots_sum'));
}]);
```

It will returns

```
"timeslots_sum" => "123" // total
```

Comment: This works great, however it returns a string. What's a good way to cast it to integer?

Comment: @FeelTheNoise You can cast it `DB::raw('SUM(CAST(min as SIGNED)) as timeslots_sum')`. I haven't test it.